# multiple matches

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove these words from text:

> John Jack David

I've written this regex:

```
(John|Jack|David)
```

But it removes `John` (first match) and doesn't match two other words.

Should I use a modifier? Which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, you need to use `preg_match_all()` in order to match all occurrences.

```
preg_match_all("/(John|Jack|David)/", $subject);
```

Comment: What about replacing after finding?

Comment: @kikio: `preg_replace` is by default global (there's no `preg_replace_all`, `preg_replace` will find and replace all matches).

Comment: @kikio: I believe it's because it's multiline. Please consider using a [CSS parser](https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention language, but in Javascript it would look like this:

```
'John Jack David'.replace(/John|Jack|David/g, 'hans');
```

Comment: I could have answered that if you had mentioned php :)